# Zero power, (2 questions)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I wasn't in school the day I had to solved this and I didn't learn how to do it.

1.)Simplify   $$2x^{−3}y^4w^2z^{−5}$$

2.)
Simplify  $$14^{−1}a^3b^{−2}c^4$$

Comment: This is too hard to read.  Is the first meant to read $2x-3y^4w^2z-5$?  If so, that's as simple as you are going to get.  Or is it $2x^{-3}y^4w^2z^{-5}$?  Why make your readers guess?

Comment: I'm not making my readers guess, I just copied what I saw.

Comment: So?  Which of my two guesses is correct?  Or am I batting zero?

Comment: Seriously, edit this. Did you mean $14-a^3b-2c^4$? Again like the previous one , it is already in its simplest form.

Comment: I mean the second one, Lulu

Comment: I can't copy and past it the correct way, it comes out as 
  2x−3y4w2z−5

Comment: Why is the tag 'calculus'? It is completely misleading!

Comment: Because I need 100 rep to make it simplify.

Comment: I edited your post, please check to make sure I got the meaning right.  I also changed the tag.

Comment: For the first, I assume you are meant to write $\frac {2y^4w^2}{x^3z^5}$ Though I'm not sure I'd call that any simpler.  Can you now do the second?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Finding information on how to format the math is probably a bit harder than it needs to be. There's a great tutorial on using MathJax  [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your expressions.  That would have short-cut most of this discussion.

Answer (score 2):

On the face of it, regardless of whether things are typeset correctly or not, there's not a whole lot to simplify.

With the expression

$$2x^{−3}y^4w^2z^{−5}$$

you could make all of the exponents positive like this:

$$\frac{2y^4w^2}{x^3z^5}$$

but that's kind of changing *happy* to *glad* in my opinion ...